# what are the other equivalent librarys of C++ qt

Tags: c++

What are the other equivalent libraries of C++ Qt ?
If anybody has used please share your experience with this community.
If anybody knows altrenative please let us know yourr experience with these libraries

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about. Are you asking for alternative libraries that have similar functionality as Qt?

Comment: yes u are right i want to make sure what i will use is right before starting project

Comment: I'd say there is 99% chance that you'll end up using `Qt` and doing so, you'll have made the best choice.

Comment: You'd get better answer if you'd add what features exactly you need - Qt covers much more ground than most libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxWidgets is a GUI library that is similar to Qt.

http://www.wxwidgets.org/

Answer (score 2):

There is [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/). This is a C library. There is also [Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/) which is a C++ wrapper around Gtk+